# Debug sql queries with Web_Debug tool in Symfony 1.4

Tags: debugging, symfony-1.4

I'm using an web application which is developed using symfony 1.4.16 with mysql. I need to see what are the sql queries running on behind some actions in the application. So in the dev mode I have enabled the web_debug in the settings.yml file.

```
dev: 
   web_debug:              true
```

Now I can see the web debug toolbar in the browser but I cannot find a place which shows running sql quires.

[image]

Should I change more settings in order to get sql queries. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

As of Sf 1.2. you can customize the webDebug panel so it is very likely that you have the DB info disabled. Have a look at this docs: http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/07-Extending-the-Web-Debug-Toolbar and you should be able to locate where you can re-enable the query panel.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing else you should do .....
[image: if you have a sql queries ran in your action ,you should see it like at image]

if you have a sql queries ran in your action , you should see it like at image

Comment: Nop. Your tabs in the image are completely different from my ones. That's not the debug menu bar I get.

Comment: never mind by the differences .... the common , the part of SQL queries if you ran a sql queries

Answer (score 0):

Edit: config/databases.yml

Add these lines:

```
dev:
  propel:
    class: sfPropelDatabase
    param:
      classname: DebugPDO
```

If you're using Doctrine, replace Propel with Doctrine.